# Modify npm dependencies for debug

Tags: npm

Say I am writing a package `A` that depends on another package `B` written by other people.

`B` is installed in `A\node_modules\B\index.js` file.

I have problems using package `B`, and I want to insert some `console.log` lines inside it. This is a temporary modification, I don't mean to fix or change the package `B`, I just want to understand what it is doing.

I have tried to modify `A\node_modules\B\index.js`, however I cannot see any effect, at runtime the old code is executed. What can be the reason? Does npm uses some kind of cache when running dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

try `npm cache clean`

I found it here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-cache

Comment: I have tried npm cache clean --force, and still nothing changes.